# Fail to create Spark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-toree

This might be a naive question.

When I am creating a spark context using pyspark from below code, after running the status of application starts appearing on spark dashboard under "Running application"

```py
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('blah').setMaster('spark://<some-ip>:8000')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

But When I am creating a spark session from code snippet below there is no status of the application shown on spark dashboard.

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder
  .appName('blah blah')
  .master('spark://<some -ip>:8000')
  .getOrCreate()
```

I am not sure why this is working like this, as I am completely new to Spark so kindly help.

Comment: resolved just one silly mistake it should be SparkSession.builder
  .master('spark://<some -ip>:8000').appName('blah blah') .getOrCreate()